# how to extaract data from file starting from 2nd line in c

Tags: c, file

Im very new to this language, can you help me:

Instead of making the user input col, row, and direction(scanf). I want to extract the data from file(format below)

From the file format i do not want to extract the first line(5,6), i only want to extract the remaining lines.

Below is a code of how to extract data from a file(using command line arguments), but this code extract the first line also, and only prints the lines.I do not want to print the line but to extract the data from a file instead of making the user input it.

File format:
colrow direction(starting from 2nd line)

```
5,6
A0 H
D0 V
C1 V
A4 H
F0 v
```

code of scanf

```
yourcolumn = getchar();
col = charToNum(yourcolumn);    //function to input column

printf("enter row");
scanf("%d",&row);

printf("h: horizontally or v: vertically?\n");
scanf(" %c",&direction);
```

Code for extracting data from file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char const* const fileName = argv[1]; /* should check that argc > 1 */
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); /* should check the result */
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        /* note that fgets don't strip the terminating \n, checking its
           presence would allow to handle lines longer that sizeof(line) */
        printf("%s", line); 
    }
    /* may check feof here to make a difference between eof and io failure -- network
       timeout for instance */

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call `fgets()` once before the loop, and ignore the string it read?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading line-by-line, I suggest you restructure you file reading to match your logic

```
while (EOF != fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", line)) {
     printf("> %s\n", line);
}
```

Is a way that one can read every line, one at a time.  You can lookup the caveats of using `fscanf` and how to adjust the code to safely read without overflowing your `line` buffer.

Then, if you want to skip the first line, your code could look like this

```
if (EOF != fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", line)) {
    // skip the first line
}
while (EOF != fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", line)) {
     printf("> %s\n", line);
}
```

And your processing logic will look a lot like your mental process.

Yes, you could use a line counter, and only process if the counter is high enough; but, it is generally better to avoid introducing variables, if you can live without them.  This is because an extra added variable doesn't make the code too hard to reason about; but, after you've repeated that "extra variable" rationale five or six times, the code quickly turns into something that's harder to maintain and harder to reason about.  By the time you hit twenty or more extra variables, the odds of maintaining the code quickly without breaking it are lower.

Comment: Remember after you `scanf` the contents into a line, you can use that line as input to read the contents into other variables based on the formatting of your file.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", line)` fails to read a line if the line is `"\n"`.  `fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", line)` is alos bad like `gets()` without a width limit.

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line also with `fgets()` into a *string* and then scan the *string* for row, direction.

```
char line[256];
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
  if (sscanf(line, "%d %c", &row, &direction) != 2) {
    printf("Invalid first line '%s'\n", line);
  } else {
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
      printf("%s", line); 
    }
  }
}
```